Implicit Treap building time in O(n) time
I have two algorithms to build an implicity from an array, one is continuously merging
Like so:
public Node nlognConvertToTreap(int[] arr){
    Node node = Node.EMPTY_NODE;
    for (int x : arr) node = merge(node, new Node(x));
    return node;
}

The other is divide and conquer style, like so:
public Node efficientConvertToTreap(int[] arr){
    return divideAndConquer(arr, 0, arr.length-1);
}

private Node divideAndConquer(int[] arr, int left, int right){
    if (left == right) return new Node(arr[left]);
    int mid = (left+right)/2;

    return merge(divideAndConquer(arr, left, mid), divideAndConquer(arr, mid+1, right));
}`

I know the first one takes nlogn time,
the divideANdConquer approach one should take O(N) because it satisfies the recursion
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(logn).
My implementation of merge() is recursive, I counted the number of merge calls in each implementation. For n = 2^20, the number of merge calls should be around 20 times more in the nlogn  implementation. However I see only 4x improvement. Can someone help me understand the issue with my analysis/implementation.

It seems to me that both approaches have similar time complexity O(N log N) and they have similar running time.
import java.util.Random;

public class Solution {

    static class Node {
        int value;
        Node left, right;
        static final Node EMPTY_NODE = null;

        Node(int value) {
            this.value = value;
            this.left = EMPTY_NODE;
            this.right = EMPTY_NODE;
        }
    }

    static Node merge(Node left, Node right) {
        if (left == Node.EMPTY_NODE)
            return right;
        if (right == Node.EMPTY_NODE)
            return left;

        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            left.right = merge(left.right, right);
            return left;
        } else {
            right.left = merge(left, right.left);
            return right;
        }
    }

    static Node nlognConvertToTreap(int[] arr) {
        Node node = Node.EMPTY_NODE;
        for (int x : arr) {
            node = merge(node, new Node(x));
        }
        return node;
    }

    static Node efficientConvertToTreap(int[] arr) {
        return divideAndConquer(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
    }

    private static Node divideAndConquer(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
        if (left == right)
            return new Node(arr[left]);
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;

        return merge(divideAndConquer(arr, left, mid), divideAndConquer(arr, mid + 1, right));
    }

    static int[] generateRandomArray(int size) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] arr = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            arr[i] = random.nextInt(size);
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 1 << 25;
        int[] arr = generateRandomArray(n);

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        Node treap1 = nlognConvertToTreap(arr);
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("nlognConvertToTreap: " + (end - start) / 1e6 + " ms");

        start = System.nanoTime();
        Node treap2 = efficientConvertToTreap(arr);
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("efficientConvertToTreap: " + (end - start) / 1e6 + " ms");
    }
}


Prints
nlognConvertToTreap: 3374.966958 ms
efficientConvertToTreap: 2923.679101 ms


Yes emprically they have the same time. But, assymtotically they should have different times right? One should be lower. So is analysis wrong?

@VihariVemuri I agree about the theoretical and empirical differences. But, that function does not seem O(N) to me. I might be wrong though.

Why not, The recursion is T(n) = 2T(n/2)  + O(logn). Since merge of two treaps takes O(log(M) where M is the max size of each treaps. Solving that recursion should give us T(n) = O(n) right?

@VihariVemuri What's time complexity of merge()? What's the time complexity of divideAndConquer()? Is the divideAndConquer time complexity = the time complexity of merge() multiplied by log(N)?

No, time complexity of merge is logM where M is the maximum size of the treaps that are merged. So time complexity for divide and conquer is the following:log(n) + 2log(n/2) + 4log(n/4) .... Said otherwise it follows the recursion T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(logn).
